# Process HTML Body Inside XSLT By FOP

Tags: xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I was trying to run below code using FOP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"/>
  
    <xsl:variable name="XML" select="/"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
           <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
         </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So is it a legitimate approach to process the HTML body inside xslt using FOP?

Command using:
fop -xml sample.xml -xsl sample.xslt -pdf sample.pdf
or
fop -xml sample.xml -xsl sample.xslt -print sample.html

Comment: As far as I am aware, Apache FOP use XSL FO input to produce e.g. PDF output, meaning XSLT should produce XSL FO and not HTML. So while any XSLT processor can produce HTML I doubt that you are able to process that (intermediary) HTML as the input to Apache FOP. There are of course by now some paged media processors that use HTML/CSS instead of or in addition to XSL-FO. I don't think Apache FOP is one of them.

Comment: Having said that it is giving me an impression apply:templates will going to be used extensively where html will be generated from xml and in case of pdf generation  apply:templates will going to be used mostly for evaluation complex data or formatting data.
This works for me for html to be generated: fop -xml sample.xml -xsl sample.xslt -foout  sample.html